# Can Azure Worker Process stop itself?

Tags: azure

Is there a way to stop the worker process by itself? I already coded in console application, which uses REST API to start and stop worker process and delete cloud service deployment. In the latest announcement, stopping worker processes will not cost anything, it is free now.

Can I make the worker process to stop itself? Is there any event in the worker process to stop itself? Please let me know.

Comment: Why don't you use what you did in your console app from your worker role itself? You can't manage instances individually in this way but you can use that same REST API to shut down the entire service.

Answer (score 1):

So I think you're referring to Worker *Roles*, right? A worker *process* would simply be something you run in your app (like a thread, a method, something). Azure Worker Roles are full VMs.

Assuming that's what you meant: The new announcement about stopping VMs does not apply to Web / Worker Role instances; it applies to Virtual Machines. And those *can* be stopped easily via REST call (or much easier via PowerShell that wraps the REST call). You *could* make that call from a Virtual Machine, which would effectively shut itself down, but I'm not so sure that's a sound idea. If you take that approach, it will be very hard for you to track the role-stop progress, since you would have just stopped the VM that made the call.

Comment: When I See documentation, "No Charge for Stopped VMs" Worker Role is also VM then there should be no cost right?

Comment: Is there a way where my console application will be running as service in On Premise , once worker process finishes its activity it will send intimation to console application which is running as a service and start deleting of cloud deployed services.

Comment: Yes - but that's up to you to implement. You could use a service bus queue, where your console app subscribes to a "completion" topic. You could use an Azure storage queue. You could have your on-premises app host a web service (REST or something similar). Many options. Then, when your console receives a message, it can simply execute a PowerShell call like `Stop-AzureVM -Name myservicename -VM myvmname`. Just remember: this is for Virtual Machines, not for worker role instances. With worker role, you can only choose to scale out / in to more / less instances.